# ImportError: No module named django_auth_ldap

Tags: python, django, python-ldap

I can't seem to get python ldap libraries to work properly with Django:

```
>>> from django_auth_ldap import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django_auth_ldap
```

I'm running Ubuntu v14.

This is what a pip freeze looks like on my working environment:

```
Django==1.9.4
django-auth-ldap==1.2.7
django-filter==0.13.0
djangorestframework==3.3.3
Markdown==2.6.5
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyldap==2.4.25.1
python3-ldap==0.9.8.4
```

(I installed ldap for python3 as well to do a sanity check)

But as I go through all the guides here, they all seem to point to the same libraries I already have except for "pip install python-ldap".

When I try to do:
`pip install python-ldap`

I just get the following result:

```
Collecting python-ldap
  Using cached python-ldap-2.4.25.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0c5p7fkj/python-ldap/setup.py", line 53
        print name + ': ' + cfg.get('_ldap', name)
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know what are the best steps I should take to get around this issue to get the library working?

I've tried doing a wget for 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap

And I extracted the files and simply used 
`python setup.py install` to the tar ball, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from this page:
https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/precise/universe/python-django-auth-ldap/

The following command seems to have done the trick:

`apt-get install python-django-auth-ldap`